# Trigger a scrolling event using multiple divs when a user scrolls using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I created two div elements

When a user scrolls div #element-b and #header-one-target reaches near the top of #header-one-target in container #element-A scrolls to the top of the page with an animation .

Currently I am using one header `<h1 id="animate-hd-b">Header One</h1>` that triggers the animation. Which works fine. But what I would like to do use multiple headers for example `<h1 id="animate-hd-b">Header One</h1>`, `<h1 id="animate-hd-c">Header Two</h1>` `<h1 id="animate-hd-d">Header Three</h1>` and animate `#header-one-target`

My Current code is below

```js
var currentPlan = $('#element-A'),
  optionsPlan = $('#element-B'),
  combinedScroll = optionsPlan.scrollTop();

optionsPlan.scroll(function() {

  var way = optionsPlan.scrollTop(),
    rate = Math.round(optionsPlan.find('#animate-hd-b').position().top - 70),
    area = currentPlan.scrollTop(),
    turf = Math.round(currentPlan.find('#header-one-target').position().top - 50),
    down = way > combinedScroll;
  combinedScroll = way;

  if (rate < 0 && down && turf) {
    currentPlan.not(':animated').animate({
      scrollTop: area + turf
    }, 700);
  }

  if (!down && area) {
    currentPlan.not(':animated').animate({
      scrollTop: 0
    }, 700);
  }
});
```

```css
#element-A,
#element-B {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100vh;
  float: left;
  overflow: auto;
}

#element-A {
  background: orange;
}

#element-B {
  background: yellow;
}

.content {
  padding-bottom: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="element-A">
  <div class="content">
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <h1 id="header-one-target">Animate This Card</h1>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="element-B">
  <div class="content">
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <h1 id="animate-hd-b">Header One</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are there `Header Two` and `Header Three` in the same `div` with `Header One` ?

Comment: @Ibra Yes it is